How to update a ViewModel from another ViewModel in WPF MVVM?
I have an application which I use to select some stuffs from Git Repository.
This is the Basic Design of the application.
The whole window has a ViewModel, inside which i have defined two instances of view models A & B represending two user controls. The View Model B, is a status bar and only have a string in it which shows a text which can be anything. The View Model A, is another user control, where i can search for User Stories. So basically i want to show the totals from View Model A in View Model B in the UI. I tried injecting VM B into A, but that doesnt reflect in the window.How can i resolve this using WPF MVVM pattern?
This is the actual design of the application.
This is the code for the MainWindow.xaml,which has two content control one is the selected window which can change based on the option user selects on the left side. Then there is status bar window, which is just a status bar where i want to show some stuffs based on the actions in the window the user selected.
<Window x:Class="ResponsiveWorkManager.Views.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:Icon="http://metro.mahapps.com/winfx/xaml/iconpacks"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:ResponsiveWorkManager.ViewModels"
    xmlns:view="clr-namespace:ResponsiveWorkManager.Views"
    xmlns:us="clr-namespace:ResponsiveWorkManager.StatusBar"
    Icon="pack://application:,,,/IconsLibrary;component/UI-48/Taskbar-Icon.ico"        
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    x:Name="winMainWindow"
    Title="MainWindow" 
    Height="780" 
    Width="1350"
    MinWidth="450"
    WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
    WindowStyle="None"
    Background="Transparent"
    AllowsTransparency="True"
    ResizeMode="CanResizeWithGrip">
<Window.DataContext>
    <vm:MainWindowViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
<Window.Resources>
    <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BoolToVisibility"/>

    <!--Data Templates-->
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:WorkItemsViewModel}">
        <view:WorkItems/>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:FoldersViewModel}">
        <view:Folders/>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:LeaveDetailsViewModel}">
        <view:LeaveDetails/>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:StatusBarViewModel}">
        <us:StatusBarControl/>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>

<Border Background="#eff2f7"
            BorderBrush="#9E1895"
            BorderThickness="5"
            CornerRadius="30,30,0,30"
            MouseDown="Border_MouseDown"
            MouseLeftButtonDown="Border_MouseLeftButtonDown">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="200"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>


        <!--Left Menu-->
        <Grid Grid.Column="0">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <!-- Menu Icon -->
            <Button Style="{StaticResource topButton}" Margin="20 28 0 35">
                <Icon:PackIconMaterial Kind="Menu" Width="15" Height="15"/>
            </Button>

            <Border Grid.Row="1" Background="#623ed0" CornerRadius="0 50 0 27">
                <DockPanel>
                    <!--Menu Logo-->
                    <Border Width="80" Height="80" Padding="3" Background="White" CornerRadius="100" DockPanel.Dock="Top" 
                        HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="20 -30 0 0">

                        <Ellipse>
                            <Ellipse.Fill>
                                <ImageBrush ImageSource="/Images/Profile_3.jpg" />
                            </Ellipse.Fill>
                        </Ellipse>
                    </Border>

                    <!--Menu Titles-->
                    <TextBlock Text="Work Manager" Foreground="White" FontSize="22" FontWeight="SemiBold" DockPanel.Dock="Top" 
                           TextAlignment="Center" Margin="15 25 0 10"/>

                    <TextBlock Text="Noxum Gmbh" Foreground="#d0bfff" FontSize="14" FontWeight="SemiBold" DockPanel.Dock="Top" 
                           TextAlignment="Center"/>

                    <Label Margin="15 0 15 0" FontSize="10" Foreground="#d0bfff" FontWeight="SemiBold" DockPanel.Dock="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Icon:PackIconMaterial Kind="SwapVerticalCircle" Style="{StaticResource menuButtonIcon}" Margin="5 0"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding VersionNumber}"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Label>

                    <!--Menu Seperator-->
                    <Separator Margin="20" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Height="0.8" Background="#7e5fdc" />

                    <!--Menu Buttons-->
                    <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Top">
                        <Button Style="{StaticResource menuButton}" Command="{Binding MenuItemClick}" CommandParameter="{x:Static vm:WindowName.WorkItems}">
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <Icon:PackIconMaterial Kind="Network" Style="{StaticResource menuButtonIcon}"/>
                                <TextBlock Text="Work Items"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Button>

                        <Button Style="{StaticResource menuButton}" Command="{Binding MenuItemClick}" CommandParameter="{x:Static vm:WindowName.LeaveDetails}">
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <Icon:PackIconMaterial Kind="GoogleAssistant" Style="{StaticResource menuButtonIcon}"/>
                                <TextBlock Text="Leave Details"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Button>

                        <Button Style="{StaticResource menuButton}" Command="{Binding MenuItemClick}" CommandParameter="{x:Static vm:WindowName.Folders}">
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <Icon:PackIconMaterial Kind="FolderAccount" Style="{StaticResource menuButtonIcon}"/>
                                <TextBlock Text="Create Folder"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Button>

                    </StackPanel>

                    <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
                        <Button Style="{StaticResource menuButton}" Command="{Binding LogoutClick}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=winMainWindow}" Margin="15 0 15 20">
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <Icon:PackIconMaterial Kind="Logout" Style="{StaticResource menuButtonIcon}"/>
                                <TextBlock Text="Logout"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Button>
                    </StackPanel>



                </DockPanel>
            </Border>

        </Grid>

        <!-- Main Content-->
        <Grid Grid.Column="1" Margin="5 35 0 0">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="35"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <!-- Search TextBox Hidden-->
            <Grid Width="300" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Visibility="Collapsed">
                <TextBlock Margin="20 0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="#b0b9c6" IsHitTestVisible="False" 
                           Panel.ZIndex="1" Text="Search Here.." Visibility="{Binding ElementName=txtSearch,Path=Text.IsEpty,Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibility}}"/>
                <TextBox x:Name="txtSearch" Style="{StaticResource textBoxSearch}" />
                <Icon:PackIconMaterial Kind="Magnify" Width="15" Height="15" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0 0 15 0" 
                                       Foreground="#b0b9c6" HorizontalAlignment="Right" />
            </Grid>


            <!-- Top Buttons-->
            <Button Style="{StaticResource topButton}" Margin="0 0 20 0" Background="#dcdcdc" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                <Icon:PackIconMaterial Kind="Cog"/>
            </Button>

            <Button Style="{StaticResource topButton}" Margin="0 0 55 0" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                <Icon:PackIconMaterial Kind="Bell"/>
            </Button>

            <!--Main Content-->
            <Border Grid.Row ="1" CornerRadius="50 0 0 0" Background="#623ed0" >
                <ContentControl Content="{Binding SelectedWindow}"/>
            </Border>

            <!--Status Bar-->
            <Border Grid.Row ="2" CornerRadius="2" Background="Transparent" Margin="2 5 0 5" >
                <ContentControl x:Name="statusBar" Content="{Binding StatusBarVM}"/>
            </Border>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Border>

The Mainwindow view model is below :
using ResponsiveWorkManager.Commands;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace ResponsiveWorkManager.ViewModels
{
    public class MainWindowViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        private ICommand logoutClick;
        private ICommand menuItemClick;
        private ViewModelBase selectedWindow;
        private StatusBarViewModel statusBarVM;
        private string versionNumber;

        public MainWindowViewModel()
        {           
            this.StatusBarVM = new StatusBarViewModel();
            this.selectedWindow = new WorkItemsViewModel(this.StatusBarVM);
            this.VersionNumber = $"Ver - {Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetName().Version.ToString()}";
        }

        public ICommand LogoutClick
        {
            get
            {
                return logoutClick ?? (logoutClick = new RelayCommand(CloseWindow));
            }
        }

        public ICommand MenuItemClick
        {
            get
            {
                return menuItemClick ?? (menuItemClick = new RelayCommand(CreateWorkItemObject));
            }
        }

        public ViewModelBase SelectedWindow
        {
            get { return selectedWindow; }
            set
            {
                if (selectedWindow != value)
                {
                    selectedWindow = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedWindow));
                }
            }
        }   

        public StatusBarViewModel StatusBarVM
        {
            get { return statusBarVM; }
            set 
            {
                if (statusBarVM != value)
                {
                    statusBarVM = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged(nameof(StatusBarVM));
                }
            }
        }

        public string VersionNumber
        {
            get { return versionNumber; }
            set
            {
                if (versionNumber != value)
                {
                    versionNumber = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("VersionNumber");
                }
            }
        }

        private void CloseWindow(object winHandle)
        {
            var myWindow = (Window)winHandle;
            myWindow.Close();
        }

        private void CreateWorkItemObject(object windowName)
        {
            switch ((WindowName)windowName)
            {
                case WindowName.WorkItems:
                    SelectedWindow = new WorkItemsViewModel(this.StatusBarVM);
                    break;

                case WindowName.Folders:
                    SelectedWindow = new FoldersViewModel();
                    break;

                case WindowName.LeaveDetails:
                    SelectedWindow = new LeaveDetailsViewModel();
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}

What i am trying to do it, when any updates happen in the selectedwindow, i want to send some texts or status to the statusbar control. The selectedWindow and statusbar has its own ViewModels.So i want to send some data from selectedWindow VM to statusbar VM so its reflected in the Window.

VM doesn't care about view, so both screenshots doesn't make much sense in presenting the requirements. You shouldn't think about VM as strictly as it's a control, rather think of data they hold and what needs to be passed and where. Typicaly if any VM has dependency, then you pass it in as constructor parameter most of times. If VM A and B are children, then it may make sense to make them unaware about each other  and rather do something to parent, which both children need to monitor. E.g. pass parent instance to children, add events to parent (optional, property changed is usually enough).

what is your IDE? if it is Paint, switch to the one which supports WPF MVVM pattern, and then post a new [mcve]

First off there's nothing wrong with A and B simply having references to each other and setting each others' properties - or even forcing each other to raise property change notifications when needed - all in the VM layer. Alternatively you might consider just making A and B a single view model, bound to both views. There's no magic or rigid rules here. Do what makes the most sense given your architecture.

One has a "model". To "look into" or interact with the model, one creates "views" (e.g. user controls).  Not satisfied to simply bind to an interface, one may create "view models" or "model views"; that binds the model to views. State is maintained in the model; so, if you want to sync "views" (the point of "view models") you update the model, and signal a property change to the view models; which in turn signal the view(s).

I assume you want "VM B" to know about the changes that are happening in "VM A". You have couple of options to accomplish this without much effort, I will elaborate on the simplest one:

Use a common state class (a manager class), which contains event that informs about changes
Example:
public class AppManager
{
    public event EventHandler<string> AppNameChanged;

    public void ChangeAppName(string newName)
    {
        AppNameChanged?.Invoke(this, newName);
    }
}

public class ViewModelA
{
    readonly AppManager _appManager;
    public List<string> AppNamesList { get; set; }
    private string _selectedName;
    public string SelectedName 
    { 
        get =>_selectedName;
        set
        {
            _selectedName = value;
            _appManager.ChangeAppName(value);
        }
    }

    public ViewModelA(AppManager appManager)
    {
        AppNamesList = new List<string>();
    }
}

public class ViewModelB
{
    readonly AppManager _appManager;

    public ViewModelB(AppManager appManager)
    {
        _appManager = appManager;
        _appManager.AppNameChanged += (sender, newName) =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"New App Name : {newName}");
        };
    }
}


Use Messeging systems (for example from Community MVVM toolkit) to send notification. Example:
public record AppNameMessage(string Name);
public class Message : ValueChangedMessage<AppNameMessage>
{
    public Message(string Name) : base(new AppNameMessage(Name))
    {
    }
}


public class ViewModelA
{
    public List<string> AppNamesList { get; set; }
    private string _selectedName;
    public string SelectedName
    {
        get => _selectedName;
        set
        {
            _selectedName = value;
            WeakReferenceMessenger.Default.Send<AppNameMessage>(new( new (value)));
        }
    }
}

public class ViewModelB
{

    public ViewModelB()
    {
        WeakReferenceMessenger.Default.Register<AppNameMessage>(this, (sender, message) =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"New App Name : {message.Name}");
        });

    }
}



Hope that help you out

In the methodogy 1, I am unable to inject dependency because i always need a deault constructor and that is removing the event subscription.

@HellRaiser this depending on the way you are utilizing ViewModel to View binding. This method should not be an issue if you are using ViewModel locator or binding via Templates (two most common ways). However, the app manager is single instance class anyways, so you can access it via making it singleton

It’s hard to understand what you're trying to achieve with your given explanation. However, from what I understand, you have a ContentControl or another UIElement with a Content attribute. You could instead add another ContentControl and split your window into two, so you have two ContentControls for the window.
<Window.DataContext>
    <StaticResource ResourceKey="ViewModelCollection" />
</Window.DataContext>
...
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="500" />
        <RowDefinition Height="100" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <ContentControl
        Grid.Column="0"
        Grid.Row="0"
        Content="{Binding MainView.CurrentView}">
    </ContentControl>

    <ContentControl
        Grid.Column="0"
        Grid.Row="1"
        Content="{Binding StatusBar.CurrentView}">
    </ContentControl>
</Grid>

To show two different CurrentViews at once, you'll need to add another class to your project. For example, you can create a StatusBarViewModel class with a RelayCommand to set the CurrentView of your status bar to the appropriate UserControl.
Furthermore, you can create a ViewModelCollection class that holds the MainViewModel and StatusBarViewModel as properties:
class ViewModelCollection
{
    public ViewModelCollection()
    {
        MainView = new MainViewModel();
        StatusBar = new StatusBarViewModel();
    }

    private MainViewModel _MainView;
    private StatusBarViewModel _StatusBar;

    public MainViewModel MainView
    {
        get { return _MainView; }
        set { _MainView = value; }
    }

    public StatusBarViewModel StatusBar
    {
        get { return _StatusBar; }
        set { _StatusBar = value; }
    }
}

Don't forget to reference your ViewModelCollection in your App.xaml and set it as the DataContext for your window:
<viewModel:ViewModelCollection x:Key="ViewModelCollection"/>

This approach ensures that you can manage multiple views and view models effectively within your window, with each content area bound to its respective view model.
